# How do I determine the distribution of a column's value in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, analytics

For example, if I have a column that represent a `Y` or `N` flag, what percentage is a `Y` and what percentage is an `N`? I know I can write a query to find each of these numbers and then calculate the percentage myself, but I figure it should be straight forward doing this in PL/SQL with analytic functions like [`NTILE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions091.htm).

```
SELECT COUNT(1), enabled_flag
FROM widgets
GROUP BY enabled_flag;
```

Gives me:

```
COUNT(1)   | enabled_flag
  123124   | Y
  234234   | N
```

I need:

```
enabled_flag | percentage
Y            |         34
N            |         56
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try an analytic function as such:

```
SELECT round(100*COUNT(1)/sum(count(1)) over (),0), enabled_flag
FROM widgets
GROUP BY enabled_flag;
```

EDIT... you can also use the RATIO_TO_REPORT function which might make it look cleaner or easier to maintain:

```
SELECT round(100*RATIO_TO_REPORT(count(1)) over (),0), enabled_flag
FROM widgets
GROUP BY enabled_flag;
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the best way, but I guess it should work.

```
select count(*) * 100 / (select count(*) from widgets), enabled_flag
from widgets
group by enabled_flag
```